# Proof of the multidimensional version of the Jensen's Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, reference-request

I'd like a reference that contains a proof of the following theorem.

> **Jensen's Inequality:** Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^d$ a integrable random
> variable. Suppose that $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ is a convex subset. If
> $f:C\to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, $\mathbb{P}(X\in C)=1$, and $f(X)$ is integrable,
> then the following propositions are true:
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}[X]\in C$
> 2. $f(\mathbb{E}[X])\leq \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$
> 3. If $f$ is strictly convex and $X$ is not a.e. constant, then $f(\mathbb{E}[X])<\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.

This [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X74900050#:%7E:text=Jensen%27s%20inequality%20f(EX)%20%E2%89%A4,infinite%2Ddimensional%20linear%20topological%20spaces.) contains a proof of a much stronger version of the previous theorem, but I'd like a more straightforward proof of that theorem.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Some crucial hypotheis is missing. Integrability of $f(X)$ is surely not true.

Comment: The author says that $Ef(X)$ **exists**. Perhaps this allows infinite values for $Ef(X)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm You're right! I just edited the question!